# How can I handle sending multiple APNS notifications when a user is offline?

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I'm designing an application that gives wait times for a theme park. One important feature is the ability for users to receive notifications when wait times change, however, sometimes multiple notifications will be sent at the same time and users could be offline for periods of time. I need these multiple notifications reliably delivered whether a user is online or not.

One option I am considering is sending a silent content-available push, then having the app fetch the notifications from the server and displays them as local notifications. But, I read silent notifications can be throttled and might be unreliable.

Another option I am considering is sending the most recent notification via APNS and add the content-available flag if there are multiple cached on the server that need to be displayed.

Is simply sending a silent content-available notification reliable enough?

Comment: I tried using content-available notifications but those do not deliver while the app is closed, which is undesirable. So now I'm stumped. How can I deliver multiple notifications to a user when their device returns online?